# Extra, blank row from PDO select on Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, pdo, count, php-7

This involves a Sqlite database, PHP 7 and PDO.  The query code is:

```
    ...
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM images');

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $images[] = [
            "image_id" => $row["image_id"],
            "date" => $row["date"],
            "photographer" => $row["photographer"],
            ...
            ];
    }
    echo $stmt->rowCount() . " rows<br>";
    echo count($images) . " images<br>";
    var_dump($images);
    return $images;
}
```

(Note: This is based on http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-php/query/ . It will be revised soon to do prepared statements, enumerating cols, etc., once the problem described here is solved.)

The echos report "0 rows" and "2 images". The `var_dump()` outputs:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(14) { ["image_id"]=> ...
```

So clearly there's an extra, empty array in the first position in the outer array.  In the calling code, which collects the `$image` array as return value, `count($array)` gives 2 not 1 (and code expecting name/value pairs in each row breaks).

The problem is, there's only one row in the table. This appears clearly on the command line: `sqlite> select * from images;` gets one row and:

```
sqlite> select count(*) as c from images;
1
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Different array syntax solved it.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM images');

$images = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $images[] = array(
        "image_id" => $row["image_id"],
        "date" => $row["date"],
        "photographer" => $row["photographer"],
        ...
        );
}
```

I'm still not clear on the reason, but this way avoids the anomalous empty row.